# В чём отличие API для мобильных приложений от API для Web-сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, api, backend, mobile

Часто в вакансиях вижу требование а-ля "Опыт разработки API для мобильных приложений". С разработкой мобильных приложений ранее дела не имел, и тут стало интересно: "А в чём принципиальная разница?". Есть ли какой-то критерий, по которому можно определить, что вот это API сделано для Web-сайта, а это для мобильного приложения, или это одно и то же? Речь, естественно, про backend.

Comment: Многие привыкли, что бакенд для сайта отдает полностью готовый html или хотя бы куски html текста. И при этом называют это API. И такой API конечно для мобилки не пойдет. Если же API полноценный, т.е. отдает чистые данные и больше ничего (например в JSON) то никакого отличия конечно нет.

Comment: Единственное с чем столкнулся, это то, что при работе с JSON при отдаче на web может быть удобна структура вида `{"a":1, "b":2, ...}` при условии, что сами a и b формируются динамически и их может быть разное количество, а на языках разработки мобильных приложений (вроде java или c#) это может быть не удобно разбирать и стоит делать `[{"name":"a", "val":1}, {"name":"b", "val":2}]`

Comment: @Mike для мобилки всё подойдёт, ничто не мешает написать парсер html-кода в мобильном приложении, ну кроме здравого смысла)